# Main Camera re-sizing in 2d

Tags: unity, 2d, camera

My UI :

[image]

An UI from [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tyAutnOlsfA) :

[image]

Look my camera's size is 10 and his camera's size is only 5. But, my camera's width is larger than height. If you look at scale (x,y,z)=(1,1,1). I tried to change them. But, nothing changes.I tried to change `ViewPort Rect` then, I am able to change the size of Main Camera. But, look at following image. His `ViewPort Rect` is 1 by 1 mine also. But, we have differences of width and height.

How to fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While D.Kallan focuses with his answer on how to make it closer to Brackeys', this answer focuses more on if you actually should do that.

Since you are new to GameDev, I would guess for now most of your projects are for yourself and the learning experience. Instead of following the tutorial to the letter, you should make the game look great on your own platform. Since the topic of handling different resolutions, fit to the screen and similar can be quite confusing (even more so when you try to learn the basics), you should fix your game to the resolution you are actually using yourself.

That means, if you plan to make a small mobile game, use a fixed aspect and enter your own mobile resolution there. If it is for pc, use your screen resolution under which you plan to play the game later. This saves you the trouble that while the game will work and looks similar to the tutorial in the editor, it might look totally different when you want to play your own game or show it to friends. Once the game is actually done and looks great on your own hardware, you can learn about the topics on how to make it look great for everybody else.

You can set a fixed resolution in the game tab.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have noticed that when your camera is on `Free Aspect`, the size changes with the size of your `game window`.

If you compare the differences between your UI and Brackeys' UI, you see that your game window is wider than his, and a little smaller vertically.

**Try resizing the game window to match his** and your camera should then match about the same ratio as Brackeys' has.